How do you use the size.width and size.height parameters when making a custom shape in jetpack compose?
I can't figure out how to create a custom shape with an adjustable size in jetpack compose. I can only create one with a fixed size.
Here is the code for a custom shape with a fixed size.
class CustomShape2: Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
   ): Outline.Generic {
        return Outline.Generic(
            path = drawShapePath(size = size))
    }
}

private fun drawShapePath(size: Size): Path {
    return Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        lineTo(x = 400f, y = 0f)
        lineTo(x = 400f, y = 400f)
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = 400f)
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = 0f)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Button2() {
    Button(onClick = {},
        shape = CustomShape2(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(500.dp)
            .height(500.dp)
            .offset(120.dp, 200.dp)
            .drawBehind {
                drawPath(
                    path = drawShapePath(size = size),
                    color = Color.Red,
                    style = Stroke(width = 10f)
                )
            }) {

    }
}

This code produces a button that is shaped like a square. The problem is the size is fixed to whatever the  coordinates in the drawShapePath function state. No matter how much I adjust the weidth and height modifiers on the button, the size stays the same.
Here is code I pulled from somewhere else.
class CustomShape1: Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline.Generic {
        return Outline.Generic(
            path = drawShapePath(size = size))
    }
}

private fun drawShapePath(size: Size): Path {
    return Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        lineTo(x = size.width * 2, y = 0f)
        lineTo(x = size.width * 2, y = size.height * 2)
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = size.height * 2)
        lineTo(x = 0f, y = 0f)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Button1() {
    Button(onClick = {},
        shape = CustomShape1(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(100.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
            .offset(50.dp, 20.dp)
        .drawBehind {
            drawPath(
                path = drawShapePath(size = size),
                color = Color.Red,
                style = Stroke(width = 10f)
            )
        }) {

    }
}

This code also produces a button with a square shape. The difference between this button and the one above is that this one has a size that can be adjusted by the button modifiers.
The shape is not formed with direct offset coordinates but something else. I don't know what to call it.
I don't understand how to use the size.width and size.height parameters. What does using them by themselves mean?
I've experimented with different math operators (+,-,*,/) and different numbers and they all produce different results but I don't understand what they mean or how to produce a desired shape using them.

Both of your drawShapePath functions have a size parameter. It contains the size of the drawing area. This object is of type Size which has a width and a height property specifying the... well, width and height.
In your version of drawShapePath you ignore the size parameter and use fixed values to draw a rectangle that will always have the size 400x400.
The other version of drawShapePath on the other hand adjusts the rectangle it draws to be dependent on the size parameter: It will have a width of twice the available drawing area's width (size.width * 2) and also the height will be double the available height (size.height * 2). I don't know why the size is doubled here, that doesn't make any sense, but the point is that it is dynamic: The size of the rectangle is directly dependent on the size of the available drawing area.
Now, when you set the Button's width and height you define the available drawing area. That's ignored by your version, the other version however will allways adjust the rectangle's shape to be double the size.
Just use the size parameter's width and height properties to calculate the desired form of your shape and you're good to go.

So if you put size.width and size.height alone without any mathematical operators, it will take up the entire size of the drawing space?

Yes, that's right.
